# First letter of jSignature capture rendering incorrectly

Tags: php

I have just started using jSignatureand have it working right through to saving the signature as a png file.However, if the signature is an initial then a space then the surname it renders as a long kinky line for the initial but the rest is accurate. To get around it at present I sign with a dash then the initial followed by surname and replace the line

```
// Loop through array pairs from each signature word
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
```

with

```
// Loop through array pairs from each signature word
for ($i = 1; $i < count($a); $i++)
```

thereby ignoring the output from the dash.

This is obviously not the way to go for other users. Any help in fixing this would be much appreciated.

```
// signature div initialised

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $sigdiv = $("#signature")

  $sigdiv.jSignature()

  $('#clearSignature').click(function (){
    $sigdiv.jSignature("reset");
  })

})


// Capture signature and post
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ajaxSaveSig.php",
    data: { signature: $('#signature').jSignature("getData", "base30"), clientid: clientid }
});


//convert signature from base30 to png and save - $data imploded to conert to string from array as jSignature_Tools_Base30.php gave an error without this line.

<?php
session_start();
// Get signature string from _POST
$data = $_POST['signature'];
$clientid = $_POST['clientid'];
$data = str_replace('image/jsignature;base30,', '', $data);
$data = implode($data);

include 'jSignature_Tools_Base30.php';

// Create jSignature object
$signature = new jSignature_Tools_Base30();

// Decode base30 format
$a = $signature->Base64ToNative($data);

// Create a image            
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1295, 328);

// Save transparency for PNG
imagesavealpha($im, true);

// Fill background with transparency
$trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

// Set pen thickness
imagesetthickness($im, 4);

// Set pen color to blue            
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Loop through array pairs from each signature word
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
{
    // Loop through each pair in a word
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($a[$i]['x']); $j++)
    {
         // Make sure we are not on the last coordinate in the array
         if ( ! isset($a[$i]['x'][$j]) or ! isset($a[$i]['x'][$j+1])) break;
              // Draw the line for the coordinate pair
              imageline($im, $a[$i]['x'][$j], $a[$i]['y'][$j], $a[$i]['x'][$j+1], $a[$i]['y'][$j+1], $blue);
         }
    }

    // Save image to a folder   
    $tm = time(); 
    $filename = '../inv/signatures/'.$clientid.'-'.$tm.'.png'; // Make folder path is writeable
    imagepng($im, $filename); // Removing $filename will output to browser instead of saving

    $_SESSION['s_signature'] = $filename;

    // Clean up
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: could you post a bit more of the for loop because you just pasted 2 same loops

Comment: It is the section in the code I provided that starts with // Loop through array pairs from each signature word. The complete loop is there.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching for an answer to this very same problem, I came across your post.  I originally thought that there was a bug in the Base64ToNative (I even filed a bug report) but it just appears that I've been using the saved image data incorrectly.  The ugly jagged line is a result of not stripping out the header portion of the stored image data.  An image data string that is exported will look like this, for example:

```
    "image/jSignature;base30,HEhda1ZDGAD_EDFddjeAD"
```

1. Take the base30 image data pulled from the database, and split off the leading "image/jsignature;" header (in case I want to handle multiple formats).
2. Split off the "base30," encoding portion of the data (again in case I want to handle differnt encodings later on).

   ```
   // Data pulled from database is stored in $imgStr
   // splits the first part
   $split = "";
   list($type, $split) = explode(";", $imgStr);

   // removes the raw encoded image data
   list($encType, $split) = explode(",", $split);
   ```
3. Then, just use the data portion of the saved image string for rendering

   ```
   $converter = new jSignature_Tools_Base30();

   // $split now just contains "HEhda1ZDGAD_EDFddjeAD"
   $raw = $converter->Base64ToNative($split);
   ```

You can now continue to use the same algorithm

```
    // Create a image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 200);

    // Save transparency for PNG
    imagesavealpha($im, true);

    // Fill background with transparency
    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    // Set pen thickness
    imagesetthickness($im, 5);

    // Set pen color to blue
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    // Loop through array pairs from each signature word
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($raw); $i++)
    {
        // Loop through each pair in a word
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($raw[$i]['x']); $j++)
        {
            // Make sure we are not on the last coordinate in the array
            if ( ! isset($raw[$i]['x'][$j]) or ! isset($raw[$i]['x'][$j+1])) break;
            // Draw the line for the coordinate pair
            imageline($im, $raw[$i]['x'][$j], $raw[$i]['y'][$j], $raw[$i]['x'][$j+1], $raw[$i]['y'][$j+1], $black);
        }
    }

    // start an output buffer to write the raw image data to
    ob_start();
       imagepng($im);
       $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Do something with the raw image data...
    <custom image handling code>

    // clean up the image resource handle
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Just to be fair to the author, I discovered the logic of handling the jSignature native arrays from http://www.reloadedpc.com/php/jquery-jsignature-php-base30-image/